# How can I block the execution of a script until another one is loaded?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, load

Suppose I load these scripts from my host webpage :

```
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/widget/widget.js?type=normal" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/widget/widget.js?type=rotation" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and I'd like to execute the second one only when the first one have finished (totally; it can contain asynch functions).

How can I do it?

Comment: How about using an asychronous javascript loader like yepnope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the whole script in a function, like this:

```
(function(id) {
    var id = setInterval(function() {
        if (!window.doneLoading) return;
        clearInterval(id);

        // The whole script file goes here
        ...
    }, 50);
})();
```

The setInterval polls the (global, sorry) variable `doneLoading`. In the first script, you have to set `doneLoading` to `true` or any other non-false value when your async function is completely loaded, like at the end of an AJAX request maybe?

**Edit**: since I'm suggesting to add a global variable to the script, it may as well add a global *function*. So instead of setting up a `setInterval` call, wrap the second script inside a function... but like this:

```
function doneLoading() {
        // The whole script file goes here
        ...
}
```

In the first script file, at the end of your callback function, just call `doneLoading()`.

Comment: Can't do it! Script should be the same, so doneLoading() could have the same value...

Answer (score 2):

You're already doing it right : the scripts are executed in the order of integration in the page, not loading.

EDIT : as MaxArt pointed, this may not be what you're looking for. His answer is a good one.
But generally, you'll want to use javascript usual patterns and event based logic to avoid this kind of problems :

- have most of your files define only classes and functions (some of them taking callbacks as parameters)
- have a `main` file launching this and calling the sequence of actions, the asynchronicity being handled via callbacks.

My main code usually looks (a little) like this :

```
$(window).ready(function() {
    var myBigEngine = new BigEngine();
    myBigEngine.init(function(){
      // do other things, no need to add other layers as user events and ajax message callback will do the rest
    });
});
```

Comment: markzzz said it can contain asynch functions, maybe XHR requests. I guess he wants to wait until they're done loading.

Comment: @MaxArt Thanks. I hadn't understood what OP really wanted. I'll see if I have something smarter to say and in opposite case I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try applying  defer="defer" attribute to second `<script>` declaration like

`<script src="http://www.mywebsite.com/widget/widget.js?type=rotation" type="text/javascript"  defer="defer" ></script>`

Answer (score 0):

you can put second script init function in window.onload event

```
window.onload = function(){

// call function from second script

}
```

or with jQuery

```
$(function(){

// call function from second script

});
```

you can event add second script with this function

```
function loadScript(src){
    var f=document.createElement('script');
    if(f){
        f.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
        f.setAttribute("src",src);
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(f);
    }
}
```